how to make the overflow row go to the next column in wkhtmltopdf?
Everything in col-6 is a string from data, including the tag. This is from a rich text input field.
I'm using Bootstrap 4.
I want to make if the element is over 100rem, the rest of the element (or text if possible) is going to the next column.

The goal is to make this render as PDF with wkhtmltopdf. But I want to achieve this in CSS first. If you can also give the supported style for wkhtmltopdf, that would be great. If you can only provide the css or bootstrap class, I will handle the rest.
the closest result is from this solution.



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style class="">
    .description-condition {
        -webkit-columns: 2;
    }
</style>
<div class="container description-condition" style="height:100rem;">
    <p></p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <strong>ARTICLE 1 - Lorem.</strong>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Facilis iste nesciunt
        eveniet debitis cumque id nemo exercitationem libero temporibus vero, iusto doloremque
        quas,
        modi distinctio sed provident ipsam sunt expedita eligendi quibusdam possimus optio.
        Facere ipsa laborum commodi similique culpa voluptate ipsam esse rem tempore a quas
        nostrum animi, quos consequuntur temporibus expedita error molestias voluptatibus
        dolorem omnis optio consequatur atque molestiae! Quia molestiae soluta placeat ex
        voluptas minima laboriosam numquam fugiat ducimus perferendis? Alias, modi. Libero
        laboriosam consectetur aliquid atque facilis ipsa, magni quo quod totam optio sed
        inventore illum, vero ipsam voluptates nemo eius, dignissimos molestiae! Quibusdam,
        vero.</p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Facilis voluptatem fuga beatae in iure harum commodi doloribus vero
        atque officia?</p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quaerat, illum.</p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quia assumenda dignissimos eos at quam reprehenderit dicta. Ad ratione
        aliquam et perferendis neque quisquam nulla, ipsam sunt, pariatur id magnam nisi quaerat
        non, assumenda aut? Ex fuga dignissimos aliquid, voluptatum id harum quo sit velit enim
        voluptatibus minima tempore sequi, explicabo quaerat ipsam quisquam facilis placeat
        molestias quia reprehenderit nisi fugit:</p>
    <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, maiores?</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <strong>ARTICLE 2 - Lorem, ipsum.</strong>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quo atque tempora doloremque earum sit beatae, fuga alias, maiores
        vero nobis quibusdam tempore porro eveniet voluptatibus quod libero! Vero voluptates
        aperiam soluta. Debitis nesciunt quia quis non corrupti culpa quo commodi, similique,
        eos excepturi velit consectetur sequi. Ratione doloremque nostrum unde ad dicta quos
        rerum asperiores provident sequi nam odit iure, facere eos aperiam, recusandae atque,
        nesciunt ullam voluptatibus placeat aliquid.
    </p>
</div>



But the closest solution not rendered properly in PDF


Welcome @aditmark! Question: what is the problem with the second code sample? Doesn't it provide the result you're looking for? (E.g. when the text exceeds 200px, it flows to the next column?)

yes. It gives me the expected result in html preview. But when it's rendered as PDF with wkhtmltopdf, the column is still one. not two
